# Please help in simple pattern program in c#

Tags: c#

I want to print the following pattern:-

```
                 1
             2   3
         4   5   6
     7   8   9  10
11  12  13  14  15
```

But I am getting the following output:-

```
               1
           2   3
       4   5   6
   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15
```

Here is the Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int spacelimit = 13, num = 1, n = 5;
            for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                for (int space = spacelimit; space >= i; space--)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0,3:D} ",num++);
                    }
                spacelimit = spacelimit - 3;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

What I am doing wrong with the spaces? I am unable to do it.

Comment: Use \t instead of spaces. You dont have to calculate spaces. Character \t will handle it

Comment: `\t` will only work if the numbers stay small

Comment: @naomik then use it twice \t\t. It should handle bigger numbers

Comment: \t not working..any other suggestion??

Comment: Set the initial value of `spacelimit` to `16`.

Comment: @PalashSachan, in for loop, if we make space >= i - 3; it is working fine. Please check below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we make space>= i-3 in for loop, as shown below, it works fine. Please check. Thanks.

```
        int spacelimit = 13, num = 1, n = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int space = spacelimit; space >= i - 3; space--) // HERE, I MADE i-3
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,3:D} ", num++);
            }
            spacelimit = spacelimit - 3;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```
int spacelimit = 13, num = 1, n = 5;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(int space = spacelimit; space >= i; space--)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,2:D} ", num++);
    }
    spacelimit = spacelimit - 2;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I have just changed `3` to `2` i.e. `spacelimit - 2` and `{0,2:D}`

Yes changing spacelimit also solves the issue with trailing spaces but this solution worked as expected ... please have a look on the image.

[image]

Comment: changing 3 to 2 not working..but as told by @Eraph to change spacelimit to 16..it works..anyway thanks all for helping :)

Comment: @PalashSachan: Have a look on the image

Comment: can u please tell me how to determine spaces if i enter the number of rows from user in this program??

Comment: @PalashSachan: This is a different question. Please frame a question for this and give me the link here till I try to make a logic for spacelimit

Comment: @PalashSachan: Did u manage to frame the question. I am very near to get the answer for it.

Comment: thanks for all the help bro..i have made the program bro..please see http://pastebin.com/m5pxMvsZ

Answer (score 1):

Set the initial value of `spacelimit` to `16`.

Comment: HI @MarcoForberg, this was actually determined as the required solution after discussion in the comments.